# Unable to print to Sharp MX-M283N with error cause 040D

Tags: macos, printing, network-printer

I'm trying to install a Sharp MX-M283N printer on a Mac OSX 10.12.6.
I download the Mac drivers from Sharp's website and install goes fine.
I try to print and the print job leaves the queue just fine.
Problem is, once the job gets to the printer, it fails.
I checked the logs and found the job result is "Stopped"
The Error Cause listed is error code 040D.
I have had very little success finding information on this error.
I seem to even be unable to find the error in Sharp's own documentation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with a user on Monday. Same model: MX-M283N. Except Mac OS 10.13 High Sierra. Same thing in the job log (040D). Turns out it needs a PS Kit installed, per this response I got when I contacted Sharp about the issue:

> Call Notes: Advised that the 040D error means the following "PostScript emulation cannot be executed (PS is unavailable). The requested job was canceled due to the following reason: (PS is not available) Please check your printer driver. Tech will advise that the PostScript Kit needs to be added.

Comment: A generic PCL6 driver works to some extent though.: https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Generic/Generic-PCL_6_PCL_XL_Printer